# How to enable iPhone Settings (bundle, plist) in MonoTouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to get the **iPhone Settings** working in a [small test app](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/08/monotouch-isoflair.html) I'm writing using MonoTouch/MonoDevelop. It's probably super basic/fundamental in Xcode...

...however I didn't immediately see how to do it in the MonoTouch examples, and after a bit of reading guessed that a `Settings.bundle` folder in the root of my MonoDevelop solution that contained a [`root.plist`](http://conceptdevelopment.net/iPhone/iSOFlair01/root.plist.htm) xml file should work.

It *kinda* did - my app now *appears* in the **Settings** window - but the actual inputs don't show up. I've tried a few different things in the `plist` (from google & Beginning iPhone Development book) but no luck so far.

Can someone point out what I've missed: either a step in the MonoTouch solution/build process or errors the format/content of my `root.plist` file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>iSOFlair</string>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>User Id</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>soUserId</string>
            <key>AutocapitalizationType</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay I figured it out -- in addition to:

1. Creating the **Settings.bundle** folder
2. Creating the **Root.plist** in the correct format (ie including correct spelling!)

I *also* set the **Build Action** in MonoDevelop to 'Content' and the **Copy to output directory** to 'Always copy' to get the IDE to copy the plist TO THE DEVICE! Pretty obvious in hindsight.

I've posted [screenshots of the steps](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/08/monotouch-settingsbundle.html) and a working [Root.plist file](http://www.conceptdevelopment.net/iPhone/iSOFlair01/Root.plist2.htm).

Comment: In Xamarin Studio Add -> New File -> IOS Settings Bundle will do all of the work for you.