# The AirshipConfig.plist file is missing and no application credentials were specified at runtime

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, urbanairship.com

I am using the [monotouch binding project](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/UrbanAirShip) to implement `Urban Airship` into my `monotouch` app.

I have added a `AirshipConfig.plist` to my project as specified in the [documentation.](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html#create-airshipconfig-plist)
However when I run my app I get the error:

```
 The AirshipConfig.plist file is missing and no application credentials were specified at runtime.
```

I am noticing the `AirshipConfig.plist` file generated by monotouch is in `XML` and the documentation describes it like

```
{
/*NOTE: DO NOT USE THE MASTER SECRET*/
"APP_STORE_OR_AD_HOC_BUILD" = NO; /*set to YES for production builds*/
"DEVELOPMENT_APP_KEY" = "Your development app key";
"DEVELOPMENT_APP_SECRET" = "Your development app secret";
"PRODUCTION_APP_KEY" = "Your production app key";
"PRODUCTION_APP_SECRET" = "Your production app secret";
}
```

Am I missing something here? What do I need to do to get my app to find the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340868/how-to-enable-iphone-settings-bundle-plist-in-monotouch) enlightened me. I needed to set  the **Build Action** in `Xamarin Studio` to `Content` and the **Copy to output directory** to `Always copy` to have the file copied to the device.